# Speech to Text using Python

Tags: python

How can I do a very accurate speech to text conversion using python ? Is it possible to do this with the use of some Python modules ? I have tried speech recognition module but failed to achieve the task. can you guys help ?

Comment: Failed as in it is not good enough? Looking at the Package Index, it supports the best few speech recognitions software already.

Answer (score 1):

"very accurate" is depends on your accent. i suggest you:

[Google Speech Recognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/)

**English is not the best choice for accuracy, you main language is. (accent)**

first, you have to install python 2.x/3.x and pyaudio. then there is an example named "Recognize speech input from the microphone" on that website, you can use it for simple translation.